# maven archiva custom archetype archetype-catalog.xml

Tags: maven-2, maven-archetype, archiva

I'm trying to create my custom archetype.

I created and deployed the archetype to the internal repository.

I'm unable to locate it when creating a new maven archetype in eclipse.
There doesn't seem to be an archetype-catalog.xml file present on the internal repository.

We are working with Apache Archiva 1.3.3 for our repository

I'm guessing that the missing archetype-catalog.xml file is the reason why we can't find the archetype in our repository.

Is there a setting that can be activated to automaticaly generate and/or update the archetype-catalog.xml file on the archiva installation?

Comment: I've found the following link: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MRM-1284 . From what i can see, it means this is currently not supported yet. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Comment: New link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MRM-1284